# Increment node values in Tree [Haskell]

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement a haskell program which increments the value of all the nodes in a tree using functors. The input & output of the functor function is a tree. I'm trying to implement it recursively but getting compilation error regarding input parameters.

**Haskell Code..**

```
data Tree v = Empty | Node v (Tree v) (Tree v) deriving (Show)

add :: Ord v => v -> Tree v -> Maybe Tree v
add _ Empty = Nothing
add v (Node val left right) = (val + v) ++ add v left ++ add v right
```

**Input**

```
add (+1) (Node 3 (Node 1 Empty Empty) (Node 7 (Node 4 Empty Empty) Empty))
```

**Output**

```
  [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( functor1.hs, interpreted )

  functor1.hs:17:34: error:
  * Expecting one fewer arguments to `Maybe Tree'
   Expected kind `* -> *', but `Maybe Tree' has kind `*'
  * In the type signature:
    add :: Ord v => v -> Tree v -> Maybe Tree v
       |
 17    | add :: Ord v => v -> Tree v -> Maybe Tree v
       |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

  functor1.hs:17:40: error:
  * Expecting one more argument to `Tree'
    Expected a type, but `Tree' has kind `* -> *'
  * In the first argument of `Maybe', namely `Tree'
   In the type signature:
    add :: Ord v => v -> Tree v -> Maybe Tree v
   |
17 | add :: Ord v => v -> Tree v -> Maybe Tree v
   |                                        ^^^^
 Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Is there some mistake in the syntax? Please help

Comment: No it is more semantics. You write `(val + v) ++ add v left ++ add v right`, but how is `(val + v) ++ add v left ++ add v right` a `Maybe Tree`? Furthermore you should write `Maybe (Tree v)`, and `v` should be an instance of `Num` as well.

Comment: Furthermore your question defines a function `add`, but the error is about `fmap1`.

Comment: You're missing parentheses: `add :: Ord v => v -> Tree v -> Maybe (Tree v)`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to implement it recursively but getting compilation error regarding input parameters.

No the errors are already at compile time, so `add` is never compiled, hence it does not work.

There are some problems with both syntax and semantics, as well as some weird design decisions.

First of all, if you write `Maybe Tree v`, Haskell sees this as `(Maybe Tree) v`, which is - as far as I understand it - not the intended result, it should be `Maybe (Tree v)` since you wrap a `Tree v` into a `Maybe`.

But using `Maybe (Tree v)` as result is already kind of weird: regardless what input treee you provide, we should always construct a *new* valid `Tree`. For an `Empty` we simply do not add any values, so `add 3 Empty == Empty`, but there are no scenarios where this could go wrong.

You also ue `Ord v` as a type constraint, which is weird, since in the function, we never use a `==`, `/=`, `<`, `>`, etc. function. We use `+`, which means we should use the `Num v`, so now our signature is:

```
add :: Num v => v -> Tree v -> Tree v
```

We can implement two cases: one for `Empty` (that stays `Empty`), and one for `Node` (that updates the value, and performs two recursive calls), like:

```
add :: Num v => v -> Tree v -> Tree v
add _ Empty = Empty
add v (Node x l r) = Node (v+x) (add v l) (add v r)
```

Your question suggests that you want to implement a `Functor`. Defining an `fmap` is quite similar to `add` here, but requires to generalize the first argument. I leave that as an exercise.

If you call it with:

```
add (+1) (Node 3 (Node 1 Empty Empty) (Node 7 (Node 4 Empty Empty) Empty))
```

The first argument is *not* a number, but a function, so you should drop the `+` in that case:

```
add 1 (Node 3 (Node 1 Empty Empty) (Node 7 (Node 4 Empty Empty) Empty))
```

producing:

```
Prelude> add 1 (Node 3 (Node 1 Empty Empty) (Node 7 (Node 4 Empty Empty) Empty))
Node 4 (Node 2 Empty Empty) (Node 8 (Node 5 Empty Empty) Empty)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but when i pass the input I'm getting the error " * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a)
   (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
 * When checking the inferred type
     it :: forall a. (Num (a -> a), Num a) => Tree (a -> a) "

Comment: But in case I don't want to change the way I call the function then will I need to change only the function arguements?

Comment: @Lucy: well as stated in the comments, you need to generalize the function a bit further (to `fmap1`), and that is left as an exercise.